# Usages of "Let" in the cases of 1) Antecedent Assumption, 2) Existential Instantiation, and 3) Labeling

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

A practice problem led me to produce the following statement (the below result is *specific* to the practice problem):

> For any non-empty interval $I$ (open or closed) in $\mathbb R$: $\forall a,b \in I \left[f(a)=f(b) \right]$

It seemed intuitive that I could conclude the function $f$ was constant over the interval $I$. In attempt to be more formal, I constructed the following claim:

$$\forall a,b \in I \left[f(a)=f(b) \right] \rightarrow \exists C \in \mathbb R \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in I \left [f(x)=C \right]$$

For the purpose of my question, I am going to *expand* the universal statements into their "full" form and use some color coding:

$$\color{blue}{\forall a,b \big( a \in I \land b \in I} \rightarrow f(a)=f(b) \big) \rightarrow \color{red}{\exists C} \in \mathbb R \text{ s.t. } \color{orange}{\forall x \big ( x \in I} \rightarrow f(x)=C \big)$$

Here is how I would prove this statement:

1. $I$ is a non-empty set and therefore $\exists y \in I$
2. $\color{red}{\text{Let }y} \text{ be an arbitrary element of } I$.
3. $\color{orange}{\text{Let  }x } \text{ be an arbitrary element of } I$.
4. By our $\color{blue}{\text{assumption}}$, we then conclude that $f(x)=f(y)$.
5. **Let** $f(y)$ be represented by the symbol $C$...i.e. $C=f(y)$.
6. Therefore, $f(x)=C$.
7. $x$ was arbitrary so we can generalize to all $x$ in $I \quad \square$

---

I have a series of questions about Step 2, Step 3, and Step 5. I very purposely used the same verb  "*let*" for the three different statements...because I have encountered all such usages of this word. I apologize in advanced if the proper math jargon that is germane to this question is lacking.

Firstly, although Step 2 and Step 3 are both introducing symbols with the same feature of belonging to the non-empty interval $I$, these two steps seem fundamentally different to me. The ability to bring the object $x$ into the argument seems to emerge naturally for proofs involving implications: I am *assuming* that $x$ is in $I$ - I refer to this as an "Antecedent Assumption" and am unsure if it has a technical name. My impression is that Step 3 **does not** depend on Step 1.

Conversely, I feel as though Step 2 can only be invoked as a consequence of Step 1. In particular, I believe this is an instance of **existential instantiation** As the color coding suggests, Step 2 is asserted in order to eventually produce the desired $C$.

Finally, Step 5 seems to be purely a labeling step. I don't believe this step corresponds to either an antecedent assumption or an existential instantiation. In fact, I have no idea what to refer to this step as in technical terms.

If someone could please provide their expertise on the distinction between these three different usages of the word "Let" (and comment on whether or not my initial attempt at describing them is correct), I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Where are you getting this "implicit assumption" that $I$ is not empty? Is it from the problem? If so, you should update your formal logic statement to include an assumption that $I$ is not empty.

Comment: @MarkSaving When I say that the interval is open or closed, it strikes me as implicitly assumed that the interval is non-empty (otherwise, why mention that it could be open or closed). If that's an unfair assumption, let me know, and I will update the question to explicitly stating "For any non-empty interval $I$..."

Comment: The empty interval is an open interval, so it is certainly an interval that is open or closed. But you're right that you would need to do case analysis and consider the cases of empty and nonempty intervals separately.

Comment: @MarkSaving ahh, I did not know that. I'll just make the change now, then. Thank you

Comment: Your practice problem statement explicitly says that $I$ is non-empty, so perhaps you should have addressed that in your claim. In step $2$, you are indeed using existential instantiation. In step $3$ you are just making an assumption that you are discharging in step $7$ where you are doing implication introduction. Step $5$ can be viewed as existential instantiation using $\exists z(z = f(y))$ whcih is provable for any $y$, via a fairly simple existential introduction. Consider writing "choose" rather than "let" in $2$, "assume" rather than "let" in $3$ and just "let $C = f(y)$ in step $5$.

Comment: In addition to Rob Arthan's suggestions, I sometimes like "take" for existential proof, as in "take $C=f(y)$". Also, I'd move step 5 to come before step 3, because to prove $\exists C \forall x...$ (as opposed to the weaker $\forall x \exists C...$) we need the choice of $C$ to not depend on $x$.

Comment: @RobArthan thank you for the input. If you could clarify the following, I would appreciate it. When you say "...which is provable for any $y$, via a fairly simple existential introduction", are you basically using this argument: for any $y$, $f(y)=f(y)$. Therefore, by existential introduction (followed by universal generalization), we have $\forall y \exists z \left(z=f(y)\right)$.

Comment: Maybe useful the post [How to interpret "let" in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4053156/how-to-interpret-let-in-mathematics). And see also [When do we use "suppose" and when "let"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68498/when-do-we-use-suppose-and-when-let)

Comment: Step 2 and 3 and conclusion 7 are simply [Universal Generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819976/natural-deduction-introduction-of-universal-quantifier-and-elimination-of-exist)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA hey, Mauro. Your comments about Step 2 seem to conflict with other’s responses. Could you please explain further?

Comment: No conflict... simplify the argument removing the ref to $I$: we can simply assume $\mathbb R$ as domain for variables. We have $\forall x \forall y (f(x)=f(y))$ from which, by Universal Instantiation: $f(x)=f(y)$. Then generalize ($x$ is not free in assumptions): $\forall x (f(x)=f(y))$ and the use Existential Intro: $\exists c \forall x (f(x)=c)$.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3990957/the-nature-of-variables-within-proofs) as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3822741/logic-justification-for-the-use-of-let-y-in-existential-proof)

Comment: Also perhaps take a look at [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/9935/372) MESE Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement you're trying to prove is actually a special case of the following statement, where $A, B$ are sets and $f : A \to B$:

$$\exists a \in A \land \forall x \in A \forall y \in A (f(x) = f(y)) \implies \exists C \in B \forall x \in A (f(x) = C)$$

The semi-formal proof goes as follows:

1. $\exists a \in A \land \forall x \in A \forall y \in A (f(x) = f(y))$ [assumption]
2. $\exists a \in A$ [$\land$-elimination, 1]
3. Introduce variable $a \in A$. [assumption]
4. $\forall x \in A \forall y \in A (f(x) = f(y))$ [$\land$-elimination, 1]
5. $\forall y \in A (f(a) = f(y))$ [$\forall$-elimination, 4, 3]
6. Introduce variable $y \in A$. [assumption]
7. $f(a) = f(y)$ [$\forall$-elimination, 5, 6]
8. $f(y) = f(a)$ [symmetric property of equality]
9. $\forall y \in A (f(y) = f(a))$ [$\forall$-introduction, 6-8 - discharge variable $y \in A$]
10. $\exists C \in B \forall y \in A (f(y) = C)$ [$\exists$-introduction, 9]
11. $\exists C \in B \forall y \in A (f(y) = C)$ [$\exists$-elimination, 2, 3-10, discharge variable $a \in A$]
12. $\exists a \in A \land \forall x \in A \forall y \in A (f(x) = f(y)) \implies \exists C \in B \forall y \in A (f(y) = C)$ [$\implies$-introduction, 1-12, discharge assumption $\exists a \in A \land \forall x \in A \forall y \in A (f(x) = f(y))$]

We see that there are two places where we introduce a new variable, on lines 3 and 6. We use the variable introduction on line 6 to prove a universally quantified statement on line 9. We use the variable introduction on line 3 to utilize $\exists$-elimination.

There is a duality here between proving a statement that begins with $\forall$ and utilizing a statement that begins with $\exists$.

Using a more formal sequent calculus might help to clear up the confusion.

The assertion $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ means that in the context $\Gamma$, we can prove $\Phi$. The context includes all variables and their types (though for simplicity we won't include $A, B,$ or $f$ in $\Gamma$). It also includes all assumed statements.

The relevant rules of the sequent calculus are:

$$\begin{array}{c}
\hline
\Gamma, \Phi, \Delta \vdash \Phi
\end{array}$$ (where $\Phi$ is a statement and $\Gamma, \Phi, \Delta$ form a context)

$$\begin{array}{c}
\Gamma \vdash T \in A \\
\hline
\Gamma \vdash f(T) \in B
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c}
\Gamma \vdash \Phi \land \Psi \\
\hline
\Gamma \vdash \Phi
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c}
\Gamma \vdash \Phi \land \Psi \\
\hline
\Gamma \vdash \Psi
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c}
\Gamma, x \in X \vdash P(x) \\
\hline
\Gamma \vdash \forall x \in X (P(x))
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c}
\Gamma \vdash \forall x \in X P(x) \; \; \; \Gamma \vdash T \in X \\
\hline
\Gamma \vdash P(T)
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c}
\Gamma, x \in X, Q(x) \vdash P \; \; \; \Gamma \vdash \exists y \in X (Q(y)) \\
\hline
\Gamma \vdash P
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c}
\Gamma \vdash T \in X \;\;\; \Gamma \vdash P(T) \\
\hline
\Gamma \vdash \exists C \in X (P(C))
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c}
\Gamma, \Phi \vdash \Psi\\
\hline
\Gamma \vdash \Phi \implies \Psi
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c}
\Gamma \vdash T_1 \in X \; \; \Gamma \vdash T_2 \in X \; \; \Gamma \vdash T_1 = T_2\\
\hline
\Gamma \vdash T_2 = T_1
\end{array}$$

For brevity, let $\Phi$ abbreviate the statement $\exists a \in A \land \forall x \in A \forall y \in A (f(x) = f(y))$. The very formal proof for you is as follows:

1. $\Phi \vdash \exists a \in A \land \forall x \in A \forall y \in A (f(x) = f(y))$
2. $\Phi \vdash \exists a \in A$ [derived from line 1]
3. $\Phi, a \in A, y \in A \vdash a \in A$
4. $\Phi, a \in A, y \in A \vdash \exists a \in A \land \forall x \in A \forall y \in A (f(x) = f(y))$
5. $\Phi, a \in A, y \in A \vdash \forall x \in A \forall y \in A (f(x) = f(y))$ [line 4]
6. $\Phi, a \in A, y \in A \vdash \forall y \in A (f(a) = f(y))$ [lines 3, 5]
7. $\Phi, a \in A, y \in A \vdash y \in A$
8. $\Phi, a \in A, y \in A \vdash f(a) = f(y)$ [lines 6, 7]
9. $\Phi, a \in A, y \in A \vdash f(y) = f(a)$ [line 8]
10. $\Phi, a \in A \vdash \forall y \in A (f(y) = f(a))$ [line 9]
11. $\Phi, a \in A \vdash a \in A$
12. $\Phi, a \in A \vdash f(a) \in B$ [line 11]
13. $\Phi, a \in A \vdash \exists C \in B \forall y \in A (f(y) = C)$ [lines 10, 12]
14. $\Phi \vdash \exists C \in B \forall y \in A (f(y) = C)$ [lines 2, 13]
15. $\vdash \Phi \implies \exists C \in B \forall y \in A (f(y) = C)$ [line 14]

Notice that we discharge the statement $y \in A$ from the context in order to prove the universally quantified statement $\forall y \in A (f(y) = f(a))$.

Notice that we discharge the statement $a \in A$ from the context in order to utilize the already proven $\exists a \in A$ and prove another statement.

Finally, the part where we say "Let $C = f(a)$" in the informal proof is best reflected on line 13, where we use the already proven $\forall y \in A (f(y) = f(a))$ to prove the statement $\exists C \in B \forall y \in A (f(y) = C)$.

These are three distinct uses of the English term "let".

Comment: I think your "14. $\Phi$ ..." should conclude with "[line 2, 13]", rather than with "[line 2, 14]". Is that correct?

Comment: Also, for your "semi-formal" proof, I am not sure I understand the distinction between lines 10 and 11. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @S.Cramer It's actually a bit subtle. Line 10 is drawing the conclusion in the context of assuming $a \in A$, while line 11 is drawing that conclusion without the context of assuming $a \in A$. To see it formally, look at lines 13 and 14 of the fully formal proof.

Comment: @S.Cramer And yes, obviously we can't use line 14 as an assumption when deriving line 14. That is a typo, and I have corrected it.

Comment: I have three points that I would really appreciate confirmation on. **Point 1**: To go from line 9 to line 10 in your formal proof, you implicitly carry out multiple steps. Firstly, you discharged the proposition $y\in A$. This creates: $\Phi, a \in A\vdash y \in A \rightarrow f(y)=f(a)$. Then, you applied *Universal Introduction* to generate: $\Phi, a \in A \vdash \forall y \left[y \in A \rightarrow f(y)=f(a)\right]$. Finally, you converted the universally quantified statement into its contracted form, producing: $\Phi, a \in A \vdash \forall y \in A \left [f(y)=f(a)\right]$

Comment: **Point 2**: To go from line 12 to 13 in your formal proof, you implicitly carry out multiple steps. Firstly, you apply a conjunction in order to create:$\Phi, a \in A \vdash f(a) \in B \land \forall y\left[f(y)=f(a)\right]$. Next, you invoke *Existential Introduction* to produce: $\Phi, a \in A \vdash \exists C \left (C \in B \land \forall y\left[f(y)=C\right]\right)$. Finally, you convert the existential statement into its contracted form: $\Phi, a \in A \vdash \exists C \in B \left(\forall y\left[f(y)=C\right]\right)$

Comment: **Point 3**: Honestly, I am really not sure how you go from line 13 to line 14 of your formal proof. My best guess is as follows: Firstly, discharge $a \in A$ to produce: $\Phi \vdash a \in A \rightarrow \exists C \in B \left(\forall y\left[f(y)=C\right]\right)$.  Now, from $\Phi \vdash \exists a \in A$, we can apply *Existential Elimination* to produce: $\Phi\vdash a \in A$. Modus Ponens then yields $\Phi \vdash \exists C \in B \left(\forall y\left[f(y)=C\right]\right)$. Are these all somewhere in the right ball park?

Comment: @S.Cramer Point 1: In the version of the sequent calculus I presented, I provided the rule for universal introduction. From $\Gamma, x \in X \vdash P(x)$, we can conclude $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \in X P(x)$. This can be viewed as a "typed universal introduction rule" in that the quantifier is over a typed variable $x \in X$. In my system, the deduction $\Phi, a \in A \vdash y \in A \to f(y) = f(a)$ is not a valid one because the variable $y$ does not occur in the context. If you're using a 1-sorted logic, then you would need to go through these extra steps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129864/discussion-between-mark-saving-and-s-cramer).